# gcloud app deploy can't find classmap paths

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy an application to Google App Engine which uses Propel ORM libraries. It works fine in local tests, but google App Engine deployment isn't working. It keeps failing and outputs this message:

[RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "vendor/bin/orm/orm" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder

This is my composer.json contents:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": ""},
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/bin/orm/orm"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev",
        "google/cloud": "^0.32.1",
        "php": "5.6.*|7.0.*|7.1.*"
},

  "require-dev": {
    "behat/mink": "^1.7",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "^3.0",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^3.0",
    "google/cloud-tools": "^0.6"
  }
}
```

As I said it works locally... If I remove the classmap configuration, the application deploys with no failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer from Google Groups:

> Hi,  'vendor/bin/orm/orm' is not a Propel internal path. You need it
>   only if you've saved your generated model classes into that directory.
>   If your model classes are in another folder (reachable via psr-4
>   autoload) you can safely remove the 'classmap' instruction. otherwise,
>   you should create manually this directory on gcloud.

Just changed the autoload class map to PSR-4 as follows:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "orm\\orm\\": "vendor/bin/orm/orm"}
    }
```

And it works. Hope this helps someone with the same issues.